# Accelerometer values behaving like tilt meter?

Tags: android, accelerometer

The values I'm getting for `accel`, `x`, `y` and `z` below are not as expected.

It seems to be acting as a Tilt sensor rather than accelerometer.

When I throw the phone in the air and catch it, the `accel` value doesn't change by more than about 10%. Contrast this to when I rotate the phone randomly, I get much larger variations of 50-100%!

What could explain this? I simply want to detect when the phone is in freefall, (and/or impacting something).

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor sensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(
        sel = new SensorEventListener(){
            @Override public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {}
            @Override public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
                        double x = se.values[0];
                        double y = se.values[1];
                        double z = se.values[2];
                        double accel = Math.sqrt(
                                            Math.pow(x, 2) +    
                                            Math.pow(y, 2) + 
                                            Math.pow(z, 2));
            }
        }, 
        sensor, 
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
   );
```

(As a side question, the values for x, y and z seem much higher than they should be, with `accel` averaging at about 50-80, when standing still? Shouldn't it be around 9.8?)

The x, y and z values seem very sensitive to changes in the orientation of the phone, but not at all representative of acceleration. Am I missing something??

Example values with phone still, lying on back:
Accel = 85.36, x = 6.8, y = 45.25 z = 30.125

Comment: What are the actual values you get, when you lay the phone flat on its face? And what do they change to when you lay it flat on its back? I don't know what units you expect to read but it seems they are not m/s^2. Most likely they are scaled directly from the accel output, and there may well be an offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to replace

```
Sensor sensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
```

with

```
Sensor sensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be because when you throw the phone it is almost the same plane or angle and at low speed, when you turn the phone it changes its course and orientation rapidly and that gives higher values for the result. Accelerometer may be a misnomer for a multi-function device, there could be a selection parameter for the function you really want to get results from.

Comment: Do you know what selection parameter that might be?

Answer (score 0):

With the phone lying on its back you should get close to zero on the X and Y sensors and about 9.8 on the Z sensor.  The 9.8 is of course due to gravity.

My first though would be that there is something wrong with the phone and would suggest trying same code on another phone.

However I notice that there is something wrong in the math but haven;t figured out what yet.

with x,y,z having the values you mention the resultant (square root of sum of squares) works out to 54.78 rather than 85.36 as you mention in your post.

I'm quite new to Java so I cannot easily spot what might be wrong and haven't had the opportunity yet to try that piece of code on my phone, but I think the math is simple enough for me to determine that the result is wrong. (or at least I hope so).

The other thing to check (assuming you figureout the math problem) is that the small change when you throw the phone in the air might simply be due to the slow response time. The accelerometer output may simply be changing too slowly so by the time the phone has landed the output wouldn't have changed that much.  The response can be improved by using SENSOR_DELAY_GAME or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST instead of normal.

By the way, shouldn't that be arg0.values[] rather than se.values[]?  Where does the se come from?  The sensor values go into the argument of the onSensorChanged (arg0 in this case) so I cannot figure out how they are supposed to end up in se. (But then again there are many things in Java I still don't understand)